# How many different pointers/levels of indirection are accessed here?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, cpu, cpu-cache

I have four classes representing an inheritance and composition hierarchy:

```
class A{
//Structure here not important
}

class B : public A{
    int a;
    shared_ptr<C> c;
}

class C{
   shared_ptr<D> d;
}

class D{
    std::list<int> e;
}
```

I then have a `vector<shared_ptr<A>>`, I iterate though and sum the `*begin()` values from the two `D std::list<int>` objects:

```
for(int i = 0; i< vec.size(); i++){
    shared_ptr<B> b = vec[i];
    shared_ptr<C> c = b->c;
    sum += *(c->d->e.begin());
}
```

I am trying to work out how many separate cache line accesses could be made per each loop iteration (if we assume the worst-case scenario where each level of indirection/pointer is stored in a different cache line).

So far I have calculated 7.25 different cache lines per iteration:

1. Accessing the `shared_ptr<A>` to `vec[i]` (this is 0.25 because `sizeof(shared_ptr<A>)/64`)
2. Accessing the `A` object `vec[i]` points to
3. Accessing the `shared_ptr<C>` c points to
4. Accessing the `C` object `c` points to
5. Accessing the `shared_ptr<D>` object for d
6. Accessing the object `D d`
7. Accessing `d`'s `std::list<int> e` pointer
8. Accessing `d`'s `*begin()` data

Is there anything I have missed? I am unsure if the objects created on the stack inside the loop (`b` and `c`) could be stored in different cache lines to the pointers they are accessing (`vec[i]` and `b->c`).

Comment: A shared_ptr object manages 2 pointers - a pointer to the shared object plus a pointer to the share-state information. The share state contains 2 atomic values: number of strong references and number of weak references.

Comment: @RichardHodges ah so when the shared_ptrs are accessed, the pointer for their reference-counting object may also cause a separate cache line load?

Comment: certainly if you are copying the shared_ptr and thus incrementing the share count. If it's pure access only I suspect not.
This line: `shared_ptr<C> c = b->c` will cause a copy and therefore an indirection + atomic increment. avoid that by returning a reference.

Comment: no-you're only de-referencing the smart pointer, not creating a copy of it on that line.

Comment: I'll add an answer to illustrate

Comment: Note that `make_shared<T>` allocates the `T` and the ref counf data adjacently, while `shared_ptr<T>(new T(blah))` does 2 allocations.

Comment: If `vec` is a `vector<shared_ptr<A>>` then `shared_ptr<B> b = vec[i]` is an error as `A` is not implicitly convertable to `B`.  You need `shared_ptr<B> = dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(vec[i])` (or `static_pointer_cast`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer added to complement conversation in the comments

here is your loop with some comments:

```
for(int i = 0; i< vec.size(); i++){
    shared_ptr<B> b = vec[i];  // create 1 copy of vec[i] - increments share cout
    shared_ptr<C> c = b->c;    // create 1 copy of b->c - increments share cout
    sum1 += *(c->d1->e.begin());  // merely dereference pointer
    sum2 += *(c->d2->e.begin());  // merely dereference pointer
}
```

you can save some copies, and therefore some cache line misses if you write it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< vec.size(); i++){
    // take reference only - no copy. 
    //const means I promise not to modify the pointer object.
    const shared_ptr<B>& b = vec[i];  

    // take reference only - no copy. 
    //const means I promise not to modify the pointer object.
    const shared_ptr<C>& c = b->c;  // dereference b (which is really vec[i])

    sum1 += *(c->d1->e.begin());  // merely dereference pointer
    sum2 += *(c->d2->e.begin());  // merely dereference pointer
}
```

Comment: it might get stored in a register, or it might be on the stack.
I appreciate your quest for efficiency. Let me give you some advice I was given 30 years ago: performance is a hardware problem, elegance is a software problem. Make your code elegant, meaningful to read and succinct. You will be amazed what a compiler can do to optimise it if you are clear about your intent and use standard idioms. If you try to second guess the compiler you will prevent it's optimiser from doing its job properly.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what is happening "under the hood"

Comment: Well the answer to that is: "it depends".
If you compile with -O0, instructions will be generated that pretty much do exactly what you write. If you compile with -O2 or -O3 and then look at the resulting machine code, you will find that the compiler saw ways to optimise your intent in ways that you would not spot in a thousand years. It will reorder your code to optimise pipelineing and cacheing, it will reorder code to remove redundant operations from loops and it will completely leave out code if it can prove that you don't need it.

Comment: suggest you compile with the -S option (produce assembler source) and then have a look. Have a look at the code that comes out with different levels of optimisiation enabled.

Comment: The problem is that downcasting from `A` to `B` requires an explicit dynamic or static cast -- so the original code is illegal as written, and you can't use a `shared_ptr<B> &` without a copy as there's no `shared_ptr<B>` to refer to...

Comment: so you need to revisit your class design and ensure that A has sufficient virtual methods to allow B etc to derive from it and perform all work through the A reference. Alternatively you can store a vector of shared_ptr<B> rather than A. At this point, without more information about the problem being solved it's difficult to advise further. HINT: if you're doing dynamic down-casts, it's likely that your design is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisDodd what is the illegal aspect of the code? I am just using polymorphism albeit through a shared_ptr?

Comment: @user997112: You can't implicitly convert from a base class pointer to a derived class pointer, as the pointed at object might be of some other derived class.  `dynamic_cast` is the normal way of doing it safely -- it will cast iff the object is of the desired derived class and yield a nullptr if it is not.